# Install package geogrid in R

Tags: r

### I have the following code, basic a error message in R. Please what can i do about. I don t know what to do. error message. Please send me codes,

Hello guys i am trying to use R with Rstudio please

```
RcppExports.cpp:4:27: fatal error: RcppArmadillo.h: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado compilation terminated.
    /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'RcppExports.o' failed
    make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘geogrid’
    * removing ‘/home/gabriel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/geogrid’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘geogrid’ had non-zero exit status
```

SEssion INFO

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)

Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default

BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0

LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0


locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8   
[2] LC_NUMERIC=C            
[3]  LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8 
[4]  LC_COLLATE=pt_BR.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    
[6] LC_MESSAGES=pt_BR.UTF-8  
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8    
  [8]  LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C        
      [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 
[12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.6   ggplot2_3.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
```

Comment: Do you have RcppArmadillo installed?

Comment: How can i check?

Answer (score 0):

The `non-zero exit status` simply indicates that there was an error during the installation of the "package".

File link https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/geogrid_0.1.0.1.tar.gz

Try with the following command:

```
install.packages('FILE_PATH', repos=NULL, type = "source",dependencies = TRUE)
```

Doing so, all the dependencies for the package will also be downloaded.
Downloading from source will recompile the package and installs.

Comment: try installing older version of this package